# How to set the render to look the same as the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, output

i'm using Eevee render and i want my scene to render/output the same as how it looks as the preview screen, because when i go to activate the textures and lights, it does look different, but i dont want to add more parameters to it, just be able to render like that look, it is possible?

I am not able to upload any image from this web navigator right now, but i mean the quality of the penultimate 'sphere' before pressing the last viewport shading option (which looks exactly like the render right now)

Comment: Could you explain specifically some of the quality loss you're experiencing?

Comment: Sorry if my english isnt that good, what i mean is that the lights are 'On' on the final render so the 'preview look' i want seems different from that option when i try to render it, what i want to achieve is a render with the same look as the viewport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use *Viewport Render Image* in the *View* menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i think that does work, is there any way to change settings there, such as sampling or resolution?

Comment: If you make sure your viewport is in camera view (numpad 0) when running a viewport render, the resolution is the same as in the ouput settings. Viewport render normally renders the viewport as is (except when in Cycles rendered preview). If it's Eevee render preview, just change the viewport sampling options. If it's any other shading modes of the viewport, try playing with the shading settings popover, and also the viewport preferences in the Preference Editor.

Comment: @L0Lock thank you very much! it works for me!